# Creating a Checklist / "Step-by-Step with Unity3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm making a checklist application.

The operation is very simple. When I click in first Toggle, it'll be disabled. When I click in second Toggle, it'll be disabled, and so on...

Like this:

[image: Checklist Application]

Now, I've it:

```
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;

public class AtivaBotao : MonoBehaviour{

    public Toggle checklits_toggle;
    public bool playersReady;

    public void Start(){   
        checklits_toggle = GameObject.Find("toggle1").GetComponent<Toggle>();
    }

    public void EnableDisable(){       
        if (checklits_toggle.interactable == true){
            checklits_toggle.interactable = false;
        }       
    }
}
```

This code works with unique toggle, but I want to scale this. I want scale it for 3, 10, 50, 100 Toggles!

How I can made it?

I think refer the own Toggle, something like: "this.GetComponent();". 
For when I'll click in Toggle, the code will understand that I am clicking ONLY ON IT.

I tried use the "this" but without successful.

Resume:

-> When I click in first toogle, it'll be disabled
-> When I click in second toogle, it'll be disabled
-> and so on...

Anyone can help me? How I can update my code to make it?

---------------------------- UPDATE ------------------------
SOLVED
https://forum.unity3d.com/threads/creating-a-checklist-step-by-step.473398/#post-3088399

Comment: In your edit you only support toggling it off when it is on.

Comment: If you've found an answer to your question you should post it as an answer, not as an edit to the question.

Answer (score 1):

Attach a script with the following code inside to every toggles :

```
private UnityEngine.UI.Toggle toggle;

void Start()
{
    toggle = GetComponentInChildren<UnityEngine.UI.Toggle>();

    if( toggle != null )
         toggle.onValueChanged.addListener( OnToggleValueChanged ) ;
    else
         Debug.LogError("No toggle component in children!", this ) ;
}

private void OnToggleValueChanged( bool isOn )
{
    if( isOn )
    {
        toggle.onValueChanged.removeListener( OnToggleValueChanged ) ;
        toggle.interactable = false;
    }
}
```

A more efficient way would be to set the toggle to public, and then, drag & drop the toggle component through the inspector. But if you have a hundred toggles, it will be tedious.

Comment: Thanks for you reply @Hellium. I can solved my trouble with another code snippet. I updated my answer. Thanks again!